# String FormatException

Tags: c#, string, exception

I'm doing an activity that asks your name, and if a number is inserted it should tell that the input is invalid.

Here's my code:

```
 try {
            Console.Write("Enter your first name: ");
            string fname = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("You're Name is: " + fname);

        }
        catch (Exception) {
            Console.Write("INVALID NAME");
        }
```

Sample output:

```
Enter you're first name: 123hjay
INVALID NAME!!
```

I know my exception is wrong; I need your help guys.

Comment: I tried this out, using the same input and it works correctly (no exceptions caught). Are you sure you don't have a similar try catch block anywhere else that's actually doing this?

Comment: Is there possibly some code missing from your question? What you have posted runs fine for 123hjay.

Comment: what the OP wants if the name starts with number, exception should be thrown

Comment: don't use exception handling for normal program flow...

Comment: @Jay what about names like John456? Is that valid?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood the purpose of exceptions.

Exceptions are thrown when a program encounters an error in its *execution*. For example assigning a letter to an int would throw an error. While opinions vary, I tend not to handle user input errors with exceptions. Furthermore, think about the logic you wrote in your code. How could the program know that entering numbers into a variable named fname is incorrect?

Write in logic into your program to test for input errors and then return an appropriate response. In your case, if you wanted to ensure that there were no numbers entered, you could do the following:

```
if (name.Any(char.IsNumber))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Name.");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: PS: Users don't tend to like it when you shout at them with CAPS ;).

Comment: In theory, it's better to say `name.Any(char.IsNumber)` than `name.Count(char.IsNumber) > 0` because the latter will have to iterate through the entire string to determine the exact count, even if there exists a number character early in the string.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen we may not know the version of C# the OP is using

Comment: @codingbiz That's of no relevance in this case. The Linq methods `Any` and `Count` were both introduced in .NET version 3.5. They are both extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

As my comment says (in the question), I didn't really get what it is you are asking, because it doesn't throw anything, but if you did want it to throw an error (also suggested by the comments), this should help:

```
        Console.Write("Enter you're first name: ");
        string fname = Console.ReadLine();

        foreach (var character in fname)
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(character))
                throw new Exception("Numbers are not allowed.");
        }

        Console.Write("You're Name is: " + fname);
```

It's very straight forward and you can read it as English and understand what I've done.
You can mess around with the code, look at similar functions with Visual Studios IntelliSense and tweak it to your needs.

If you need, add a try & catch blocks, of course.

Answer (score -3):

for the courtesy of replying back, here is the answer.

Hint: your exception is right!

Enter in your console "Glee" it will not throw exception.

If you type "7337" it does throw exception.

try to use : fname.ToString();

Comment: You don't seem to have read the question; he's **not** getting that exception (and he *shouldn't* be!)